# Does ansi C support Windows graphics?

Tags: c, user-interface

I want to make a Windows application in ansi C but I am having trouble with the graphic usage. Is ansi C able to handle the graphics of Windows without using any extra libraries? Guide line required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSI (or more modernly ISO) C is the *language standard*. It doesn't deal with graphics, **at all**.

However, you sure can write graphical applications with C (the language). On Windows you have the Win32 API, and there are also cross-platform libraries like GTK, which you can use to create graphical applications on Windows (as well as on other OSes).

Answer (score 2):

The original [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383749(VS.85).aspx) was written to be accessed via C, that was the main language for developing Windows apps back in the day. I can't immediately see why you couldn't use ANSI C to write graphical Windows programs.

I was worried about GDI+ (I've never used it from C), so [looked it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(VS.85).aspx). It says it's a class-based API "...for C/C++ programmers." Taken literally, that would mean you can use C to access it (otherwise it's for C++ programmers, but not C programmers), but you'd want to look closely to be sure they're not just being loose with their language there.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the two answers above mine. One could in principle find a strictly ANSI C graphics *library* for Windows. But if the goal is to have graphics portability cross-platform, that would require the library to be available on the platforms which are under consideration. If, on the the other hand, the goal is to do something with the ANSI *standard library* graphicswise, nothing like that exists as it is way too unportable (and would have likely been even more so when the first ANSI standard was published).